# Why is there a weevil on top of a beetle?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, behaviour

A click beetle was walking around and there is a weevil on top of it.

Any idea why? I would also like to know the exact species of these insects.

[image: a weevil on a click beetle] !

Time: 18:50, place: Netherlands / Noord-Hollands / Overveen / the Amsterdamse waterleiding duinen / it's in the dunes near forest and grasslands near the dunes

Comment: Where and when was the picture taken?

Comment: That's probably a small male mating with a big female. Like in this photo: https://www.naturepl.com/stock-photo-dor-beetle-geotrupes-stercorarius-smaller-male-riding-on-back-of-image01585111.html

Comment: @personjerry No, they are completely different species from different families; Curculionidae and Elateridae it seems.

Comment: Just to be clear; for species-ID questions we consider them off-topic (*Too broad*) if they do not contain time and location (and preferably the environment and circumstances for the observation).

Comment: Time: 18:50, place: Netherlands / Noord-Hollands / Overveen / the Amsterdamse waterleiding duinen / it's in the dunes near forest and grasslands near the dunes. Thanks for the family names! I just really wonder why the click beetle was giving a "beetle ride" to the weevil. I thought that maybe the weevil was sucking out the beetle, but weevils only suck on trees right?